# Kafka JDBC Source Connector is not reading data from mysql with sql query?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have created a local database for testing purpose on MySQL. When I'm trying to read the data from the database, it's reading fine. When I use the SQL query in connector configuration, it's just running but not reading any data from the database. Any idea what might cause this?

Here is my connector config:

```
name=just-like
acks=0 
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBtest?user=**&password=**
connection.user=**  
connection.password=**  
table.whitelist=test
mode=timestamp  
timestamp.column.name=createddate  
query= select column_name from table_name  
validate.non.null=False 
topic.prefix=sql-
```

Database Schema

[image]

Comment: Can you show your table schema and current data in the table? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: You may want to review your configuration, because as posted it seems to be invalid (multiple properties on a single line), which might well be the cause of your problem (but given you botched the initial formatting of your post, I can't be sure).

Comment: Please have a look on question again. i have added required details.

Comment: Rather than just `"select column_name from table_name"`, can you please show the actual query? And `table.whitelist=test` wouldn't read from `table_name`, so that seems wrong. And then `localhost:3306/DBtest user=**&password=**` has a space in it, so I don't think that is correct

Comment: I have tried as you suggested but as soon as i put sql command it stopped working and when i remove query it's working fine and pulling data but it's fetching all columns from a table and i want to access few. Please let me know.

Comment: I haven't used the JDBC connector to pull a few columns. Usually I write Kafka Streams or KSQL code to do column filtering and other translations

Comment: do we any other alternate to pulling selected columns from table.

Answer (score 1):

We shouldn't use the tag **table.whitelist** with the custom query. If you want to use the query tag, I suggest removing the table.whitelist tag. You can't use them both together.